# Place session variable value in the Text of label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I have some labels inside a DataList which are populated with text from as the DataList is binded with database. Now i want to place the value of Text of asp.net with Session variable.

```
<asp:DataList ID = "dl_cmt" runat="server">
      <ItemStyle CssClass="coment" />
             ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="ll" runat="server" Text='<%#  %>'  />
                 <asp:Label ID="lblcmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ecomment")%>' />
                 <asp:Label ID="lblDate" style=" color:brown; font-family:Cursive; font-size:x-small; " runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("my_date","on {0}") %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want to place the text of label `ID="ll"` with `session["userid"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the value as follows

```
ll.Text = Session["userid"].ToString();
```

*Another approach*:

You can also `hide` the implementation details from the `aspx` code with a `property`

.cs file

```
public string userid { get { return Session["userid"]; } }
```

.aspx file

```
<asp:Label ID="ll" runat="server" Text='<%= userid %>' >
```

Comment: can i use the function instead of property.I mean i need to select `session["pic"]` where `userid = session["userid"]`.

Comment: You can use function.

Comment: what if I wanted to use the session as an sql query condition to display data based on its value from my database table in a grid view?

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

`<asp:Label ID="ll" runat="server" Text='<%#Session["yourvariable"]%>'/>`